# Injecting text to HTTP in Node Red

Tags: ibm-cloud

Please find below a simple node red flow for text injection, to an HTTP. 
Somehow this simple flow is not working. Any ideas? 10x

```
[ 
  {
    "id":"78a282df.875d7c",
    "type":"http in",
    "name":"http in",
    "url":"/sam",
    "method":"get",
    "x":146,
    "y":154,
    "z":"b93245a4.46cdb8",
    "wires": [["a40ab436.5bf548"]]
  },
  {
     "id":"2e6d576f.d192a8",
     "type":"template",
     "name":"",
     "field":"",
     "template":" {{ msg.payload }}",
     "x":469.00006103515625,
     "y":179,
     "z":"b93245a4.46cdb8",
     "wires":[["e206965a.1df968"]]
   },
   {
     "id":"e206965a.1df968",
     "type":"http response",
     "name":"http response",
     "x":643,
     "y":129.00003051757812,
     "z":"b93245a4.46cdb8",
     "wires":[]
   },
   {
     "id":"cf597c3c.30a68",
     "type":"inject",
     "name":"Inject1",
     "topic":"payload",
     "payload":"Injection",
     "payloadType":"string",
     "repeat":"",
     "crontab":"",
     "once":false,
     "x":155.00003051757812,
     "y":79,
     "z":"b93245a4.46cdb8",
     "wires":[["a40ab436.5bf548"]]
   },
   {
     "id":"d773e361.288c2",
     "type":"debug",
     "name":"Debug1",
     "active":true,
     "console":"false",
     "complete":"true",
     "x":578.0000610351562,
     "y":49,
     "z":"b93245a4.46cdb8",
     "wires":[]
   },
   {
     "id":"a40ab436.5bf548",
     "type":"function",
     "name":"",
     "func":"return {payload:msg.payload};\n",
     "outputs":1,
     "valid":true,
     "x":306,
     "y":111,
     "z":"b93245a4.46cdb8",
     "wires":[["2e6d576f.d192a8","d773e361.288c2"]]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple problems with your flow.

1. the Function node is not passing through the message object it received - it is returning a new message object with just the payload. This means the original request/response objects provided by the HTTP In node are not being passed through to the HTTP Response node. This means the flow cannot reply to the original request.
2. the Template node is trying to insert `{{ msg.payload }}`. As per the examples in the sidebar help for the node, it should just be `{{ payload }}`.